# Word2vec in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, word2vec

I am trying to apply word2vec to check similarity of two columns per each row of my dataset.

For instance:

```
Sent1                                     Sent2
It is a sunny day                         Today the weather is good. It is warm outside
What people think about democracy         In ancient times, Greeks were the first to propose democracy  
I have never played tennis                I do not know who Roger Feder is
```

To apply word2vec, I consider the following:

```
import numpy as np

words1 = sentence1.split(' ')
words2 = sentence2.split(' ')
#The meaning of the sentence can be interpreted as the average of its words
sentence1_meaning = word2vec(words1[0])
count = 1
for w in words1[1:]:

    sentence1_meaning = np.add(sentence1_meaning, word2vec(w))
    count += 1
sentence1_meaning /= count

sentence2_meaning = word2vec(words1[0])
count = 1

for w in words1[1:]:
    sentence1_meaning = np.add(sentence1_meaning, word2vec(w))
    count += 1
sentence1_meaning /= count

sentence2_meaning = word2vec(words2[0])
count = 1
sentence2_meaning = word2vec(words2[0])
count = 1
for w in words2[1:]:
    sentence2_meaning = np.add(sentence2_meaning, word2vec(w))
    count += 1
sentence2_meaning /= count

#Similarity is the cosine between the vectors
similarity = np.dot(sentence1_meaning, sentence2_meaning)/(np.linalg.norm(sentence1_meaning)*np.linalg.norm(sentence2_meaning))
```

However, this should work for two sentences not in a pandas dataframe.

Can you please tell me what I need to do for applying word2vec in case of a pandas dataframe to check similarity between sent1 and sent2? I would like a new column for the results.

Comment: Have sentences in a column. Calculate `word2vec` sentence representation. Calculate [square] pairwise distance matrix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have `word2vec` trained and available, so I will show how to do what you want with a bogus `word2vec`, with words converted to sentences by `tfidf` weights.

**Step 1**. Prepare data

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
df = pd.DataFrame({"sentences": ["this is a sentence", "this is another sentence"]})

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(df.sentences).todense()
vocab = tfidf.vocabulary_
vocab
{'this': 3, 'is': 1, 'sentence': 2, 'another': 0}
```

**Step 2**. Have bogus `word2vec` (of the size of our vocab)

```
word2vec = np.random.randn(len(vocab),300)
```

**Step 3.** Calculate a column containing word2vec for sentences:

```
sent2vec_matrix = np.dot(tfidf_matrix, word2vec) # word2vec here contains vectors in the same order as in vocab
df["sent2vec"] = sent2vec_matrix.tolist()
df

sentences   sent2vec
0   this is a sentence  [-2.098592110459085, 1.4292324332403232, -1.10...
1   this is another sentence    [-1.7879436822159966, 1.680865619703155, -2.00...
```

**Step 4.** Calcualte similarity matrix

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
similarity = cosine_similarity(df["sent2vec"].tolist())
similarity
array([[1.        , 0.76557098],
       [0.76557098, 1.        ]])
```

For your `word2vec` to work you will need slightly adjust Step 2, so that `word2vec` contains all the words in `vocab` in the same order (as specified by value, or alphabetically).

For your case it should be:

```
sorted_vocab = sorted([word for word,key in vocab.items()])
sorted_word2vec = []
for word in sorted_vocab:
    sorted_word2vec.append(word2vec[word])
```

Comment: Hi Sergey Bushmanov, thank you so much for your answer. I would have a question: what you showed, it is the whole code to replace mine, or it is just something to integrate in mine? I am considering texts from two different columns and I would like to compare for each row sentence in Sent1 and sentence in Sent2. For my understanding (but probably I misunderstood) your code compare two rows in the same column. Could you please let me know if I misunderstood what you showed me? Thanks a lot

Comment: My suggestion is to change your approach to having just one column with sentences (i.e. change the code of youts to mine). If you still insist on having the text in 2 df columns, you still can apply `cosine_similarity`, but the way you're doing it is way too complicated for me. I would do just 3 things: define `sent2vec` function, apply it to both columns, apply `cosine_similarity` between 2 columns. But to be honest, I never saw it done this way.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, Sergey. What I was trying to do is to compare similarity between texts, one in col1 and another one in col2, rather than in rows. You can think of it like headlines and corpus of an article, for instance. I will opt for your approach, but the important thing is to keep the comparison between the two columns rather than rows, as they mean different thing to me.